# Creating Observable in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, gltf, threejs-editor

I have a function that receives JSON data on surface mesh from a server end-point and it looks this way and works perfectly.

```
public getSurfaceMeshJSON(componentId: number, decimate: number): Observable<any> {
        let activeUrl = new URL(this.serverAddress);
        let surfaceMeshKey: string = componentId.toString() + "." + decimate.toString();
        let targetUrl = new URL(activeUrl.origin + environment.apiBasePath + '/surface_mesh/' + componentId + "?decimate=" + decimate);
        let params:{ [name: string]: string }  = {};

        if (this.customLookupAddress != "") {
            params['lookup']=this.customLookupAddress;
        }
        if (this.customGatewayAddress != "") {
            params['gateway']=this.customGatewayAddress;
        }
        if (params){
            Object.keys(params).forEach(key => targetUrl.searchParams.append(key, params[key]))
        }

        const data$ = new Observable(observer => {
            fetch(targetUrl.toString(), {headers: { 'responseType': 'json'}, method: 'GET'})
              .then(response => response.json()) 
              .then(surfaceMesh => {
                observer.next(surfaceMesh);
                observer.complete();
              })
              .catch(err => observer.error(err));
          });

        return data$.pipe(
            map((surfaceMesh) => {
                this.surfaceMeshes.set(surfaceMeshKey, surfaceMesh);
            }
        )
       
        )    
    }
```

The above function works perfectly fine. I need to create a similar function that instead of receiving JSON data format, it receives GLTF data format (octet-stream) from the end-point. I was wondering how would that be looking? I created something like this but I don't think it's fully correct.

```
 public getSurfaceMeshGLTF(componentId: number, decimate: number): Observable<any> {
        let activeUrl = new URL(this.serverAddress);
        let surfaceMeshKey: string = componentId.toString() + "." + decimate.toString();
        let targetUrl = new URL(activeUrl.origin + environment.apiBasePath + '/surface_mesh_gltf/' + componentId + "?decimate=" + decimate);
        let params:{ [name: string]: string }  = {};

        if (this.customLookupAddress != "") {
            params['lookup']=this.customLookupAddress;
        }
        if (this.customGatewayAddress != "") {
            params['gateway']=this.customGatewayAddress;
        }
        if (params){
            Object.keys(params).forEach(key => targetUrl.searchParams.append(key, params[key]))
        }

        const data$ = new Observable(observer => {
            fetch(targetUrl.toString(), {headers: { 'responseType': 'application/octet-stream'}, method: 'GET'})
              .then(response => response.arrayBuffer() 
              .then(data => {
                const loader = new GLTFLoader()
                loader.parse(data, "", gltf => {
                    observer.next(surfaceMesh);
                    observer.complete();
                  })}))                
              .catch(err => observer.error(err))
          });

        return data$.pipe(
            map((surfaceMesh) => {
                this.surfaceMeshes.set(surfaceMeshKey, surfaceMesh);
            }
        )
       
        )    
    }
```

I tried using the GLTF Loader of the three.js library but I am not sure of the syntax for the same or even if it's necessary. It would really mean a lot if you help me out with this. If you could write down the entire function for me, it would be meaning a lot as I am very new in coding and this would help me out a lot with regards to my first project.

Comment: i don't have the anserw but why are you using `fetch? instead of  the built-in HttpModule?
and why are you creating a new observable with `new Observable(observer` insted of `from(etch(targetUrl.toString(), {headers: { 'responseType': 'application/octet-stream'}, method: 'GET'})).pipe( )`

Comment: Hi. I am not supposed to use the built-in HttpModule in this case. I can of course do as you said but would that be okay with loading the data as it is an octet-stream and not json?

Comment: I don't see any reason why it' should not work, no matter if json, octet-stream or blob.  `from(fetch())` should alway work. But you need to see what you do with that octet-stream afterwards...

Comment: So first you should not have any side effects in map. I think your method should be reduced to only do the data fetching. You can make this a lot easier by using async/await und simply return a promise. And then in the place you need an observable you can wrap it with from as mentioned above. The Observable you are creating in your example is a lot of overhead that has no actual use over using a Promise.